# How can we handle the Map object from server side in GWT application?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, smartgwt, gxt

Usually we handle **List** or **Set** objects as **JsArray** in the client side (GWT application). Is there any such way to handle Map objects?

For example :

Earlier my server side DTO was

```
public class CustomDTO {

    private Users users;

    public CustomDTO(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public Users getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }
}
```

**So in the GWT application I have the following code to get it**

```
public final class CustomDTO extends JavaScriptObject {
    protected CustomDTO() {
    }
    public native JsArray<UsersOverlay> getUsers() /*-{return this.users;}-*/;
    }
```

But now my server side DTO is as below

```
public class CustomDTO {

    private Users users;

    private Map<Employee, List<Taskss>> tasksMap = Maps.newHashMap();

    public CustomDTO(Users users, Map<Employee, List<Taskss>> tasks) {
        this.users = users;
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    public Users getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Users users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<Tasks> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Tasks> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

So I have the following code in the client side now,

```
public final class CustomDTO extends JavaScriptObject {
    protected CustomDTO() {
    }
    public native JsArray<UsersOverlay> getUsers() /*-{return this.users;}-*/;
    public native Map<Employees, JsArray<Tasks>> getTasks() /*-{return this.tasks;}-*/;
}
```

Is this correct or Is there any other way to handle Map objects? Since I am getting ClassCastException if I handle this way? If I try this way:

```
final List<Map<Employees, JsArray<Tasks>> list = new ArrayList(); 
for (int i = 0; i < List<CustomDTO>.length(); i++) { // where List<CustomDTO> is the response from the server 
  list.add(List<CustomDTO>.get(i).getTasks()); 
} 
//**Upto this line it works. I got the ClassCastException in the following line** 
for (Map<Employees, JsArray<Tasks>> map : list) { 
}
```

Please refer the following image:

[image]

Comment: Why are you converting map into jsarray?  Do you not able to access same object without converting?

Comment: Map can be accessed on GWT client side.

Comment: Bhumika, I am not converting map into JsArray. I tried to access the same object but getting Exception. Please see the edited question.